# ViewPager Imageview is showing issue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, imageview

I am using imageview inside the viewpager and i want to show the image centerInside the image view but its not showing in a good view. Imageview provides in the left and right side of imageView blank space. But in some cases its shows good view.

This is my viewpagerAdapter

```
private class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    public ImagePagerAdapter(){
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if(visibleImagesCount==0){
            return 1;
        }
        return visibleImagesCount;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((RelativeLayout) object);
    }

    /**
     * Following method is responsible to load images into ViewPager
     * @param container
     * @param position
     * @return
     */
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

        final Context context = getActivity();


LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        RelativeLayout relativeLayout= (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_pager_fragment,null);

        final ImageView imageView= (ImageView)relativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.view_pager_image_view_show);

        RequestManager glide=Glide.with(getContext());
        {

                List<Image> list = dbHelper.getAllVisibleImagesList();


                Image image = list.get(position);

                final String filePath = Constants.Path.IMAGE_LOADING_PATH + imageName;
                Bitmap bitmap;
                if(image.getImageStatus() != ImagesStatus.STATUS_IMAGE_ADDED.getStatus())
                    bitmap = ImageUtils.getBitmap(thumbURL);
                else
                    bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.black_image);

                Drawable d = null;
                if(bitmap != null /*&& image.getImageStatus() != ImagesStatus.STATUS_IMAGE_ADDED.getStatus()*/){
                    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
                    float dpHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels / displayMetrics.density;
                    float dpWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels / displayMetrics.density;
                    float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
                    int marginHeightP = (int) (dpHeight * scale + 0.5f);
                    int marginWidthP = (int) (dpWidth * scale + 0.5f);
                    d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, marginWidthP, marginHeightP, true));
                } else{
                    d = (getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pikard));
                }


                glide.load(filePath)
                        .placeholder(d)
                        .fitCenter()
                        .listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {

                            @Override
                            public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, com.bumptech.glide.request.target.Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                                return false;
                            }
                            @Override
                            public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, com.bumptech.glide.request.target.Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                                pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
                                return false;
                            }

                        }).into(imageView);

            }
        }
        container.addView(relativeLayout, 0);
        return relativeLayout;
    }
}
```

And this is my XML file which i am using for using image inside the view pager

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:androd="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/view_pager_image_view_show"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is showing image like this inside the imageview when i set the scaleType centerInside[image]

but i want to show images inside the imageview like this
[image]

[image]

Comment: You want your image view as last image you added. You can use fitXY but it will strech out your image.

Comment: @MohamedMohaideenAH fitXY does not fit the image centerInside()

Comment: I want to show the image centerInside  the imageView and but its showing blank spaces left and right side of imageView :(

Comment: Try `fit_center` option. CenterInside() cannot change the ratio of image. You can find more here [Android Imageview Scaletype](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/android-imageview-scaletype-a-visual-guide)

Comment: fit_center is also not working

Comment: `fit_center` is your needs, share your image which is not fit on you. i will check.

Comment: i am using fit_center but its showing blank spaces left and right side of imageView :(

Answer (score 0):

See this output.

**xml**

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/view_pager_image_view_show"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/canoe_water_nature_resized"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**OUTPUT**

ScaleType - fitCenter

[image]

**EDITED**
This is what happen when your image height is larger than screen height. It aligned the image based on x-axis. So you got space at left & right.

[image]

This is what happen when your image width is larger than screen width. It aligned the image based on y-axis. So you got space at top & bottom.

[image]

**Solution**
Try to reduce the image height maximum equal to screen height.

Comment: Its not working like this for full screen image into viewpager. Please add into full screen image.

Comment: full screen image provides blank spaces left and right side into viewpager

Comment: @Salman i got your point if this happens due to your image height is higher than the screensize.

Comment: What can i do for it

Comment: @Salman Only way is set fitXY to set image to full width it stretch the image to fill.  Otherwise you can show only part of image to fill width if your image is large potrait image.

Comment: fitXY is not my requirement dear